# Unable to find Refresh button in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am new to Notepad++ and beginner in coding.

I am using NP++ v8.5.4 (32-bit).
My device:Windows 10. System:64-bit operating system.
I am having difficulties:

1. I want to have 2-screens side-by-side.
   One side for coding and the other to see result (pics, output of text etc.)
2. There is no Refresh/Review button, to see the output.

I have tried many ways but without any joy.

I would be most grateful if someone can help.

Thanks in advance
Khalid

Comment: Which language are you coding in? You are probably better off using an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) to code.

Comment: if I'm understand you correctly, my experience has been that if I have a document open in notepad++, and its contents have changed on disk due to another program modifying it, when I next click in the Notepad++ window you will see a dialog message saying something like "the content of this document has changed. would you like to load the latest version?" with yes/no buttons. so if I want to refresh the document I just click yes.

Comment: @FrankThomas I think they want something like https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/live-editing.html (click on the GIF to play it) but NP++ is not an IDE but a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

The refresh command in Notepad++ is found in the menu.

Use menu *File > Reload from Disk*.

The keyboard shortcut is
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,
but this can be changed via menu *Settings > Shortcut Mapper...*.